pt-archiver lost rows when cancelled in the middle and reinitiated
Lost some 430 rows from the original table.
I was archiving 1 year old data (1st Apr 2022 to 31st Mar 2023) from one of my servers, (Server version: 5.7.44-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)) using pt-archiver (percona-toolkit-3.0.13-1.el7.x86_64). Because the server choked, because of less resources and the Linux machine was not responding and swapping a lot, I had to cancel pt-archiver in the middle after a lot of attempts to take a shell session.
I waited for good 15 minutes or so and then had to kill the mysqld process, shutdown the EC2 machine, increase the hardware and then reinitiate the pt-archiver tool.
The mysql server had
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog = 1

I was thinking that above config would save my data even if I cancel pt-archiver in the middle, but it doesn't seem so.
SO before I initiated the archival, I had taken a count of rows in the said range and after archival, I had checked the count and it seems 430 rows are missing.
Following are the command I used
mysql --login-path=archiver --skip-column-names --silent SOURCE_DB -e "select count(*) from SOURCE_DB.SOURCE_TABLE where crt_tm between date_format('2022-04-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') and date_format('2023-03-31 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')" &>> pt-archiver-LOGFILE.log

Here it showed 21713301 rows
pt-archiver --source h=SOURCE_HOST,P=PORT,u=USER,p=PASS,D=SOURCE_DB,t=SOURCE_TABLE,i=idx_crt_tm --dest h=DEST_HOST,P=PORT,u=USER,p=PASS,D=ARCHIVE_DB,t=ARCHIVE_TABLE --where "crt_tm in (select crt_tm from (select crt_tm from SOURCE_TABLE where crt_tm between date_format('2022-04-01 00:00:00','%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00') and date_format('2023-03-31 23:59:59','%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')) AS temp) " --charset=UTF8 --sleep 5 --progress 10000 --limit=5000 --txn-size 5000 --replace --bulk-insert --bulk-delete --statistics --purge  &>> ${LOGFILE}

When I checked the SOURCE_TABLE, I have zero rows in that date range. and the final count of rows in the ARCHIVE_TABLE is 21712871.
Is it possible to lose data in such way? Is there any way to get the data back? And yes once the row is inserted, in the database it is never updated or deleted, meaning that the data being archived does never get and updates or deletes on it. Did I miss any important option in the pt-archiver command?
Attached is an excerpt of the log file.

2024-10-22+20:22:04: Table SOURCE_TABLE ... Archival from 01-Apr-2022_00-00-00 till 31-Mar-2023_23-59-59 started.
Archiving table from SOURCE_DB.SOURCE_TABLE ...... to 172.21.90.94 ARCHIVE_DB.ARCHIVE_TABLE. 2024-10-22 20:22:04
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Follwoing are the total number of rows being archived. 
21713301
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
First Run
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
  at /bin/pt-archiver line 4907.
Exiting on SIGINT.

# A software update is available:
TIME                ELAPSED   COUNT
2024-10-22T20:22:14       0       0
2024-10-22T20:23:04      50   10000
2024-10-22T20:24:48     154   20000
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
2024-10-23T00:21:10   14335 1360000
2024-10-23T00:21:10   14335 1360000
Started at 2024-10-22T20:22:14, ended at 2024-10-23T00:23:33
Source: A=UTF8,D=SOURCE_DB,P=3306,h=SOURCE_HOST,i=idx_crt_tm,p=...,t=SOURCE_TABLE,u=pt_archiver
Dest:   A=UTF8,D=SOURCE_DB_archive,P=3306,h=DEST_HOST,i=idx_crt_tm,p=...,t=ARCHIVE_TABLE,u=pt_archiver
SELECT 1365000
INSERT 1360000
DELETE 1360000
Action              Count       Time        Pct
bulk_deleting         272 12986.3633      89.69
sleep                 272  1360.7520       9.40
bulk_inserting        272    56.9958       0.39
select                273    36.9763       0.26
commit                546     5.5169       0.04
print_bulkfile    1360000    -3.0093      -0.02
other                   0    35.8642       0.25
2024-10-23+00:23:34: Table SOURCE_DB.SOURCE_TABLE ... Archival from 01-Apr-2022_00-00-00 till 31-Mar-2023_23-59-59 End.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Second Run
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2024-10-23+00:43:28: Table SOURCE_TABLE ... Archival from 01-Apr-2022_00-00-00 till 31-Mar-2023_23-59-59 started.
Archiving table from SOURCE_DB.SOURCE_TABLE ...... to 172.21.90.94 ARCHIVE_DB.ARCHIVE_TABLE. 2024-10-23 00:43:28
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Follwoing are the total number of rows being archived.
20353301
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TIME                ELAPSED   COUNT
2024-10-23T00:43:40       0       0
2024-10-23T00:45:00      80   10000
2024-10-23T00:46:50     190   20000
2024-10-23T00:48:22     282   30000
        ...
        ...
        ...
        ...
2024-10-24T05:43:38  104397 20340000
2024-10-24T05:43:49  104408 20350000
2024-10-24T05:43:54  104414 20353301
Started at 2024-10-23T00:43:40, ended at 2024-10-24T05:43:59
Source: A=UTF8,D=SOURCE_DB,P=3306,h=SOURCE_HOST,i=idx_crt_tm,p=...,t=SOURCE_TABLE,u=pt_archiver
Dest:   A=UTF8,D=ARCHIVE_DB,P=3306,h=DEST_HOST,i=idx_crt_tm,p=...,t=ARCHIVE_TABLE,u=pt_archiver
SELECT 20353301
INSERT 20353301
DELETE 20353301
Action              Count       Time        Pct
bulk_deleting        4071 83296.8183      79.77
sleep                4071 20355.7030      19.49
select               4072   157.4209       0.15
bulk_inserting       4071   143.8715       0.14
commit               8142    46.2508       0.04
print_bulkfile   20353301   -17.9404      -0.02
other                   0   437.3239       0.42
2024-10-24+05:43:59: Table SOURCE_DB.SOURCE_TABLE ... Archival from 01-Apr-2022_00-00-00 till 31-Mar-2023_23-59-59 End.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

